# Supremum of a set of cardinalities.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let $A$ be a set of cardinalities. Does $A$ have a supremum among all cardinalities. How about infimum?

Answer (score 8):

Assuming the axiom of choice, then the answer is trivially yes.

Cardinals are ordinals, and the supremum is a well-defined notion for non-empty sets of ordinals; as is infimum. In fact, as ordinals are well-ordered, the infimum is in fact a minimum.

Without the axiom of choice one can easily arrange for situation where no infimum nor a supremum exist. For example if there is an infinite Dedekind-finite cardinal, then the set of finite ordinals does not have a supremum, and the set of infinite cardinals smaller than a fixed Dedekind-finite cardinal does not have an infimum either.